# NullPointerException quando executo um teste Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Eu estou com uma certa dificuldade em instanciar o driver em outra classe. O que acontece é o seguinte:

Tenho duas classes de definição de etapas

Primeira:

```
public class TranscricaoSadtStep {

    static WebDriver driver = Web.openBrowser();
    Autorizacoes_InicialPage inicial;
    AutorizacoesSite_Page autorizacoes;
    TranscricaoSadt_Page sadt;
    Atendimento_Page atendimento;

    @Given("^que acessei o menu transcricao$")
    public void queAcesseiOMenuTranscricao() throws Throwable {
        inicial = new Autorizacoes_InicialPage(driver);
        inicial.navigateTo();
        this.inicial.selecionarUsuario("MARCELO DA SILVEIRA MACHADO");
        this.inicial.clickQaAutorizacoes();
        String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        autorizacoes = new AutorizacoesSite_Page(driver);
        this.autorizacoes.trocarAba(oldTab, 0);
        this.autorizacoes.menuTranscricao();
    }

    @Given("^cliquei no submenu SADT$")
    public void cliqueiNoSubmenuSADT() throws Throwable {
        this.autorizacoes.submenuSadt();
        sadt = new TranscricaoSadt_Page(driver);
    }
```

Segunda:

```
WebDriver driver;
AutorizacoesSite_Page autorizacoes;
TranscricaoInternacao_Page internacao;
Atendimento_Page atendimento;

@Given("^cliquei no submenu solicitacao de internacao$")
public void cliqueiNoSubmenuSolicitacaoDeInternacao() throws Throwable {
    autorizacoes.submenuInternacao();
    internacao = new TranscricaoInternacao_Page(driver);
}
```

Ou seja, ele executa o primeiro passo da classe 1 e depois tenta executar o primeiro passo da classe 2, pois é assim que está escrito na feature.

Só que ocorre `NullPointException` quando ele tenta executar na classe 2. E eu já sei que o motivo é que o driver está nulo, mas não sei como inicializá-lo.

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: Boa noite, tudo bem? Pelo que eu li, você precisar realizar uma implementação deste WebDriver. Tem um material no link a seguir contendo a implementação no FireFox e no Chrome. Link: https://artoftesting.com/automationTesting/launching-browsers-in-selenium.html

Comment: Na verdade o WebDriver já está implementado. Ele abre o navegador, executa a step da classe 1 e depois ele deve executar a step da classe 2. E é nesse momento que ele fica null. O que eu preciso é que ele execute o step da classe 2 na mesma janela aberta, pois é a continuação do teste. Ou seja, ele abre o navegador, clica no menu (step da classe 1) então deve clicar no submenu desse menu (classe 2).

Answer (score 0):

voce precisara de uma classe que inicia e retorna o driver antes de comecar os testes e depois carregar esse driver ate o fim da execucao como voce ja faz em seus contrutores. as classes que recebem esses drivers precisam extender da classe que cria o driver. pois assim voce utiliza a mesma instancia.
Exemplo

metodo que cria a instancia do driver:

```
public class CriaDriver(){

 public WebDriver getDriver() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromewindows/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
     }
    }
```

steps de teste que recebem o metodo:

```
public class Teste1 extends CriaDriver{
    private WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver;

  public Teste1(WebDriver driver){
    driver = getDriver();     

  }
  public void realizaTestesAqui(){
    //aqui voce faz seus testes
  }
}
```

Classe de teste 2

```
public class Teste2 extends CriaDriver{
    private WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver;

  public Teste1(WebDriver driver){
    driver = getDriver();     

  }
  public void realizaTestesAqui(){
    //aqui voce faz seus testes
  }
}
```